# Trying to open all .png files in windows viewer from batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a batch file that is setup to open all `*.png` `*.jpg` `*.gif` file types in windows viewer. My issue is that with the `for /r %%G in` command, it will open all files in sub-directories too.

I am aware of the FOR /D syntax, but I cannot seem to get it to work in correlation with this issue. If anyone can point me in the right dirrection, it would be much apeichiated.

**Will open all files including in sub-directories:**

```
for /r %%G in (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) do start "c:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" %%G
```

**Will open all files in current directory** (Not working)**:**

```
for /d /r %%G in (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) do start "c:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" %%G
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a batch file:

```bat
@For %%A In (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif
) Do @Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "%%A"
```

---

From the Command Prompt:

```bat
For %A In (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) Do @Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you tried to over complicate (/r made it to go in dir tree and commas where missing) , this

```
for %G in (*.png, *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif) do (start "c:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" %G)
```

should work; (double %% if from script)